# Wordpress HTTP 500 Error "page isn’t working"

Tags: http, 500-internal-error

Last week I came across "**HTTP 500 error**" on my website and i managed to solve it by deleting all folders in theme directory and then reinstalling theme from admin panel.

Today I faced same issue. I don't think there is any problem with theme. Although by deleting theme folders i could solve problem.

**My config:**
VPS Hosting: Ubuntu, Nginx, WP(latest);
RAM: 1GB;
CPU: 1;
Storage: SSD;
Theme: Ribon Lite;
SSL: Cloudflare Free flexible SSL;

Today I increased memory limit to 500MB by editing wp-config.php. Is it possible problem maybe with memory limit. What can i do so i dont get into same problem again.

Comment: One way is to check the Nginx access and error logs, that will give you an idea of what's wrong if it's not related memory resource handling.

Comment: enable config by changing define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php then you can see the error.

Comment: WordPress debug file is located at /wp-content/debug.log. Within this file you search for the latest fatal error. Whether it's a memory cap issue or not will be visible within the debug.log file.

Comment: @BasvanDijk After  define('WP_DEBUG', true); there is no  debug.log file inside the wp-content/, what i need to do, how can i find the error?

Comment: @Gem `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` does not trigger the actual logging of the errors. You should also use `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`